# Sniffing network requests

Tags: android, sniffing

I am looking for a way to sniff the network traffic my Android app is generating. The reason is I want to check and send statistics of the traffic generated by a third party tracking library I am using in my app.

Because of this, I cannot use any [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&hl=en) or similars.

I have no access to the http client of this tracking library, so I cannot intercept any request.

I already took a look to `VpnService`, but I cannot force the user to connect to a VPN every time he is using my app of course.

So I am looking for any advice on how to do this in Android, if it is possible.

I found that there is this library, [NetworkEye](https://github.com/coderyi/NetworkEye), which is doing exactly what I would like to do... but for iOS.

Comment: not sure that you can do that if your device is not rooted. Also DDMS could be useful: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#network

Comment: can you pass your tracking library a custom http client? (btw, which tracking lib is it?) in which case [Stetho](https://facebook.github.io/stetho/) might work for you

Comment: @njzk2 no I cannot. It's called Adjust. You can find it on github too.

Comment: since the lib is open-source, yes you can. here: https://github.com/adjust/android_sdk/blob/master/Adjust/adjust/src/main/java/com/adjust/sdk/Util.java#L293  you can inject stetho sniffing. (or whatever other sniffing you want ot use)

Comment: I am not really fan of code injection, but anyway, what if I am using also GTM? which is not open source

Comment: Btw, by injecting code  you mean writing a gradle script which inject code into that point when compiling right? In that case, I need to download the source code of Adjust, loosing the chance to get any update coming from maven. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, to achieve 'global' packet sniffing in Android OS you have to run on a rooted device. 
For the library,I would go through the NDK and [libpcap for Android](http://blog.umitproject.org/2011/05/libpcap-for-android.html)